# Change SVProgressHUD's ring and text to different color

Tags: ios, swift, svprogresshud

I'm using SVProgressHUD in my Swift project and I want different color's for the ring and text. If I'm changing using:

```
SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.blue)
```

than all the hud's and text of SVProgressHUD changes to blue. Is there any way i can show blue hud and black text using SVProgressHUD.

Answer (score 1):

SVPrrogressHUD does not provide any public API for this customization.

This issue was raised earlier on Github's page. But now the issue is closed as they planned to keep 'SVProgressHud' as simple as possible.

More detail [here](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD/issues/461).